# query to find if one barcode is assigned to multiple order in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table where we have barcodes and order numbers, so, I am trying to find all the barcodes that are being assigned to multiple orders.

Example table

| barcode | ord_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1233 | 1 |
| 1234 | 2 |
| 1233 | 3 |
| 1235 | 4 |
| 1236 | 5 |
| 1237 | 6 |
| 1235 | 7 |
| 1238 | 8 |

expected output

| barcode | ord_no |
| --- | --- |
| 1233 | 1 |
| 1233 | 3 |
| 1235 | 4 |
| 1235 | 7 |

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is to find barcodes you need (b_mult) and then join them to themselves in order to find order numbers

```
select *
  from barcodes b
  join (select barcode
                    from barcodes
                   group by barcode
                  having count(1) > 1) b_mult
     on b.barcode = b_mult.barcode
```

an [example](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jyoMCicNSZpjMt4jFYoz5/0)

Answer (score 1):

Use a window function:

```
with find_multi as (
  select barcode, ord_no, 
         count(*) over (partition by barcode) as item_cnt
    from order_item
)
select barcode, ord_no
  from find_multi
 where item_cnt > 1;
```